# Azure WebApps leaking handles "out of nothing"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have 6 WebApps (asp.net, windows) running on azure and they have been running for years. i do tweak from time to time, but no major changes.

About a week ago, all of them seem to leak handles, as shown in the image: this is just the last 30 days, but the constant curve goes back "forever". Now, while i did some minor changes to some of the sites, there are at least 3 sites that i did not touch at all.

But still, major leakage started for all sites a week ago. Any ideas what would be causing this?

I would like to add that one of the sites does only have a sinle aspx page and another site does not have any code at all. It's just there to run a webjob containing the letsencrypt script. That hasn't changed for several months.

So basically, i'm looking for any pointers, but i doubt this can has anything to do with my code, given that 2 of the sites do not have any of my code and still show the same symptom.

[image]

Comment: Without lots of details or seeing your code, it will be nearly impossible to answer this question. Have you recorded a memory dump for analysis yet?

Comment: This has clearly nothing to do with my code, as nothing has changed in 3 of these sites, as i mentioned. one site only consists of a single webjob, containing the letsencrypt script. i am looking for stuff pointing somewhere else. why do you think somethink like this might be caused by application code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears this is a problem with azure. Here is the relevant part of the current response from azure technical support:

==>
We had discussed with PG team directly and we had observed that, few other customers are also facing this issue and hence our product team is actively working on it to resolve this issue at the earliest possible. And there is a good chance, that the fixes should be available within few days unless something unexpected comes in and prevent us from completing the patch.
<==

Will add more info as it comes available.

Comment: Here is the final info from the product team:
----------

Answer (score 3):

## Final information from the product team:

The Microsoft Azure Team has investigated the issue you experienced and which resulted in increased number of handles in your application. The excessive number of handles can potentially contribute to application slowness and crashes.

Upon investigation, engineers discovered that the recent upgrade of Azure App Service with improvements for monitoring of the platform resulted into a leak of registry key handles in application worker processes. The registry key handle in question is not properly closed by a module which is owned by platform and is injected into every Web App. This module ensures various basic functionalities and features of Azure App Service like correct processing HTTP headers, remote debugging (if enabled and applicable), correct response returning through load-balancers to clients and others. This module has been recently improved to include additional information passed around within the infrastructure (not leaving the boundary of Azure App Service, so this mentioned information is not visible to customers). This information includes versions of modules which processed every request so internal detection of issues can be easier and faster when caused by component version changes. The issue is caused by not closing a specific registry key handle while reading the version information from the machine’s registry.

As a workaround/mitigation in case customers see any issues (like an application increased latency), it is advised to restart a web app which resets all handles and instantly cleans up all leaks in memory.

Engineers prepared a fix which will be rolled out in the next regularly scheduled upgrade of the platform. There is also a parallel rollout of a temporary fix which should finish by 12/23. Any apps restarted after this temporary fix is rolled out shouldn’t observe the issue anymore as the restarted processes will automatically pick up a new version of the module in question.

We are continuously taking steps to improve the Azure Web App service and our processes to ensure such incidents do not occur in the future, and in this case it includes (but is not limited to):
•   Fixing the registry key handle leak in the platform module
•   Fix the gap in test coverage and monitoring to ensure that such regression will not happen again in the future and will be automatically detected before they are rolled out to customers